# Https with Android

Tags: http2

I used

For client :
OkHttp 3.11.0
Retrofit 2.4.0
Android > 8.1
For server:
Server: nginx/1.14.0

When I request a api, then the response protocol (response.protocol()) is http/1.1. But My Server supported for http2. Please help me, how to config to switch to http2. Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you consulted the documentation?

Comment: May you want to read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask